# setting tabIndex for table row not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

This is my sample table format :

This is my code for dynamically setting tabIndex for `<tr>`(perfectly working in Chrome and FF but not on IE 8) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <style>
            td {
                color: blue;
            }
            :focus {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("tr").attr( "tabIndex", function ( i ) {
                    return i + 1;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Five</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Four</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Three</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Two</td></tr>
                <tr><td>One</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help how to fix setting tabIndex on table row that works all on browers,especially on IE8?

Comment: give your tr a class and try again or use $("#myTable tr") without tbody

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef nothing change sir.

Comment: that what IE is ..hope you will solve it or anyone help you.. Good Luck

Comment: Your selector starts with `#myTable`, but your sample table code doesn't have an `id` attribute on the `<table>` itself. Show us the *actual* code you're working with, please.

Comment: @JonathanSampson my fault sir. Already added id on table but still problem on tab index on IE.

Comment: The `table` markup is invalid; both occurrences of “Second cell” appear between cells, not inside any cell.

Comment: The `tabindex` attribute was not valid for `tr` in HTML 4, and IE 8 might just follow that. The conclusions and workarounds on what you expect to achieve by making a table row part of the tabbing order.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela text on input already changed, typo again. Can you give me some hit or workaround to work tabIndex in <tr>?

Comment: Do you know what IE version @JukkaK.Korpela that support tabIndex for tr?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela can you give me links as this one I only heard from  you sir, Im glad I heard this `The tabindex attribute was not valid for tr in HTML 4, and IE 8 might just follow that` but can you point me on article to get more details? thanks.

Comment: I cannot repro the issue in IE 8 with [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0ecux3e/show/).

Comment: Make sure you're using a version of jQuery that supports IE 8 (a 1.x version).

Comment: @bumbumpaw, HTML 4.01 on `tabindex`: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex

Answer (score 2):

In HTML 4.01, the `tabIndex` attribute was limited to a smaller set of *focusable* elements that did not include table rows. I suspected this may have been the case for the issue you're facing, but after standing up a single test on JSFiddle, I found that IE 8 was actually handling the code appropriately.

Here's a quick demo I stood up to test the issue:

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>Five</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Four</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>One</td></tr>
</table>
```

```css
:focus {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```js
$("tr").attr( "tabIndex", function ( i ) {
    return 5 - i;
});
```

And as you can see in the following GIF, IE 8 worked as expected.

[image]

So what could the issue be? Check your version of jQuery; jQuery 2.x versions don't support Internet Explorer 8. If you'd like to support a browser half-a-decade old, you'll need to use jQuery 1.x versions.

Comment: Do you know what IE version that support tabIndex for tr?

Comment: IE documentation is inconsistent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx does not mention `tr` at all, but the `tr` documentation mentions `tabindex`.

Comment: @bumbumpaw Which version of jQuery are you using? Does the my fiddle above work for you in IE 8?

Comment: @JonathanSampson 1.10.2 , it works on fiddle sample,but I cant work it on my code and on window.open which containing table,Sorry for late reply but can you check why its not working on my code. See updated post above please.

Comment: @bumbumpaw Would you be available today to jump into a Hangout? I suspect we could probably get to the bottom of this with just a few minutes of remote debugging.

Comment: Ok sir @JonathanSampson can we do it after 10hrs from now? Thanks :) also can you check my another question here related to tabIndex issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261722/how-to-set-tabindex-on-keydown-or-keyup-given-the-activeelement-tabindex