# How to set tabIndex on keydown or keyup given the activeElement tabIndex?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    var code = e.which;
    var currentTabIndex = document.activeElement.tabIndex;
    if (code == 40) {
        alert(currentTabIndex);
        //set tabIndex to currentIndex + 1;
    } else if (code == 39) {
        alert(currentTabIndex);
        //set tabIndex to currentIndex + 1;
    }
    else if (code == 38) {
        alert(currentTabIndex);
        //set tabIndex to currentIndex - 1;
    }
    else if (code == 37) {
        alert(currentTabIndex);
        //set tabIndex to currentIndex - 1;
    }
});
```

see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xLvvmswy/) for demo.

Comment: Can you describe what it is you're attempting to achieve?

Comment: @JonathanSampson If button keyup is press, tabindex focus should be the element BEFORE the current element having the tab Index focus,else if button keydown is press, tabindex focus should be the element AFTER the current element having the tab Index focus :)

Comment: So if they press the up arrow, focus on the first element with a smaller `tabIndex` the the activeElement. If they press the down arrow, focus on the first element with a `tabIndex` larger than the activeElement?

Comment: @JonathanSampson smaller tab Index means currentTabIndex - 1 and larger tab Index means currentTabIndex + 1? then yes. :)

Comment: @JonathanSampson also if the user is on input field, I dont want the tabIndexing to trigger just the normal left and right cursor should do on input field text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.filter()` to select the element that has a desired `tabIndex` and then use `.focus()` like so:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return this.tabIndex == currentTabIndex + 1;
}).focus();
```

Set focus to any element and then press the **down arrow** in the following demo:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/xLvvmswy/1/)

**UPDATE**

And here is how you would prevent *tabbing* if the active element accepts text input and either the <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> is pressed. **The following is the complete code**:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    var code = e.which,
        elm = document.activeElement, //capture the current element for later
        currentTabIndex = elm.tabIndex,
        nextTabIndex = code == 40 || code == 39 ? currentTabIndex + 1 :
    code == 38 || code == 37 ? currentTabIndex - 1 : null, //calculate next tab index
        isHoriz = code == 39 || code == 37; //Left or right arrow pressed
    $('[tabindex]').filter(function() {
        if( !$(elm).is(':text,textarea') || !isHoriz ) { //Exclude left/right arrow for text inputs
            return this.tabIndex == nextTabIndex;
        }
    })
    .focus();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/xLvvmswy/4/)

Comment: if the user is on input field, I dont want the tabIndexing to trigger just the normal left and right cursor should do on input field text.

Comment: Refine your selector to include only the elements you want to target, eg by using .not('input')...

Comment: For that you want to not fire the code provided if the active element is a text input and the user presses left or right arrows. An if statement around the code would do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say just grab the element with the next or previous `tabindex` and call `.focus()` on it:

```
$("[tabindex='" + (currentTabIndex + 1) + "']").focus();
```

or

```
$("[tabindex='" + (currentTabIndex - 1) + "']").focus();
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xLvvmswy/3/)

EDIT:

So you want to stop the function if ('key pressed' == 'left arrow' or 'right arrow') and 'input type' == 'text'?  Then write an if statement doing that exact thing:

```
if ((code == 39 || code == 37) && $(e.target).attr('type') == "text") return;
```

Put this at the second line of the function.

Comment: ,if the user is on input field, I dont want the tabIndexing to trigger just the normal left and right cursor should do on input field text.